# Fetch a set of referenced objects into an array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

How can I fetch a set of referenced objects into an array, without having to overly use async tasks? For an example,

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    accessRights: [{
        role: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Role',
            required: true
        },
        account: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Account'
        }
    }]
};
```

How can I fetch and initialize an array of accessRights without async waterfall? Because this looks like spaghetti code in this case where I have a set of references within one object.

Comment: pls . just post your excepting output

Comment: Well, the array accessRights should contain full models of role and account, not just their references.